# Check if ANY coupon code is applied in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements, checkout

How do I check if ANY coupon is applied to a product in WooCommerce at checkout?

Everything I see checks for ID or slug, or an array of them, but I want to adjust some fields at checkout based on whether or not there's a coupon, any coupon.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to check for a specific coupon, @Reigel's answer is the solution. However to check if ANY coupon has been applied the following code will get the job done.

```
if( WC()->cart->get_coupons() ) echo "Coupon applied";
```

Comment: This works. I also tried @Reigel which also worked. Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `has_discount()` function of the cart.. this needs the coupon code as argument.

Use it like this:

```
if (WC()->cart->has_discount('test1')) {
   // cart has coupon test1 applied
}
```

---

as suggested by @Anand, you can use `WC()->cart->get_coupons()`. This will return all the coupons if there are any in the cart.

However, as I've check woocommerce plugin source code, `get_coupons()` is using `WP_Query`.
It's really not a big deal if there's no other better way.

Here's a better way. We can access a public variable of the cart `applied_coupons`. It contains an array of coupon codes applied to the cart. We can use it like this...

```
$has_coupons = count(WC()->cart->applied_coupons)>0?true:false;
if($has_coupons) {
   // cart has coupons
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this check for a specific coupon (ie 'test1' coupon)? I don't need anything so specific.

Comment: ahh yes,,, sorry, but someone already suggested `WC()->cart->get_coupons() ` and that's the correct one